# How do I prevent my last nested attribute from being destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, nested-attributes

I have a customer model that has_many phones like so;

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :phones, as: :phoneable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, allow_destroy: true
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phoneable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I want to make sure that the customer always has at least one nested phone model. At the moment I'm managing this in the browser but I want to provide a backup on the server (I've encountered a couple of customer records without phones and don't quite know how they got like that so I need a backstop).

I figure this must be achievable in the model but I'm not quite sure how to do it. All of my attempts so far have failed. I figure a before_destroy callback in the phone model is what I want but I don't know how to write this to prevent the destruction of the model. I also need it to allow the destruction of the model if the parent model has been destroyed. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
before_destory :check_phone_count

def check_phone_count
  errors.add :base, "At least one phone must be present" unless phonable.phones.count > 1
end
```